# Handling SQL Null Parameters Elegantly

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I'm generating an `SQL` statement by checking if each of the column fields submitted to the query are empty (== null) or not. It seems that my approach is pretty naive so I'm wondering what can be done about handling null parameters elegantly. When something isn't specified it should simply match anything.

Here is the code:

```
public List<Flight> findMatchingFlights(Flight flight)
{
    List<Flight> foundFlights = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder sqlQueryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    sqlQueryBuilder.append("SELECT * FROM Flights");
    boolean emptyQuery = true;

    if(flight.getDeparture() != null)
    {
        if(emptyQuery)
        {
            sqlQueryBuilder.append(" WHERE ");
            emptyQuery = false;
        }

        sqlQueryBuilder.append("Departure = '" + flight.getDeparture() + "'");
    }

    if(flight.getArrival() != null)
    {
        if(emptyQuery)
        {
            sqlQueryBuilder.append(" WHERE ");
            emptyQuery = false;
        }
        else
        {
            sqlQueryBuilder.append(" AND ");
        }

        sqlQueryBuilder.append("Arrival = '" + flight.getArrival() + "'");
    }

    if(flight.getFlightNumber() != null)
    {
        if(emptyQuery)
        {
            sqlQueryBuilder.append(" WHERE ");
            emptyQuery = false;
        }
        else
        {
            sqlQueryBuilder.append(" AND ");
        }

        sqlQueryBuilder.append("Number = '" + flight.getFlightNumber() + "'");
    }

    if(flight.getFlightMinutes() != 0)
    {
        if(emptyQuery)
        {
            sqlQueryBuilder.append(" WHERE ");
            emptyQuery = false;
        }
        else
        {
            sqlQueryBuilder.append(" AND ");
        }

        sqlQueryBuilder.append("Duration = " + flight.getFlightMinutes());
    }

    /*
    ...
    A bunch more fields
    */

    if(flight.getAirplane() != null)
    {
        if(emptyQuery)
        {
            sqlQueryBuilder.append(" WHERE ");
        }
        else
        {
            sqlQueryBuilder.append(" AND ");
        }

        sqlQueryBuilder.append("Airplane = '" + flight.getAirplane() + "'");
    }

    sqlQueryBuilder.append(";");

    // Execute sql and fill list with rows that match
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create the common method for the below block and call the method by passing the arguments.

```
if(flight.getArrival() != null)
    {
        if(emptyQuery)
        {
            sqlQueryBuilder.append(" WHERE ");
            emptyQuery = false;
        }
        else
        {
            sqlQueryBuilder.append(" AND ");
        }

        sqlQueryBuilder.append("Arrival = '" + flight.getArrival() + "'");
    }
```

Comment: Not quite. This code snippet modifies two variables which makes it impossible to extract the method. Also there are different datatypes involved such as `int` which need to be handled slightly differently than `String`...

Answer (score 1):

Best approach would be to do the trick in SQL than checking for null in Java. This is how you can do it.

```
sqlQueryBuilder.append("(Number = '" + flight.getFlightNumber() + "' OR " + flight.getFlightNumber() + " IS NULL)");
```

This way you wont have to check null in java, if the flight.getFlightNumber() is null then this where clause will always return true which is what you would want.

The only drawback to this method is that the clause will be included in the query, but since you are intending to use these columns to query the table incase they are not null, i would assume the table would be indexed likewise.

Comment: Are you sure that `flight.getFlightNumber()` should be inside the String in the `OR` clause and not an actual Java method call?

Comment: Thats right the value should be appended, updated the answer with correct one.

Comment: Such OR expressions usually cannot be optimized with indexes.

Comment: @CL.  When you make such statements please provide relevant references, rather than misleading. Esp in this case where the second part of the OR clause does not have any column involved.

Comment: @CL. Quoting from the URL you sent. "Each subterm is analyzed as if it were itself the entire WHERE clause in order to see if the subterm is indexable by itself. If every subterm of an OR clause is separately indexable then the OR clause might be coded such that a separate index is used to evaluate each term of the OR clause." So even the documentation dont claim what you are claiming. And in the reply i did not claim that it this query would be blazing fast. All i said was if the table is indexed it wont be as slow. I totally dont understand the downvote as thats not the question asked.

Comment: For more than one column, the expression does not have a form that can be optimized.

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlQueryBuilder.append("SELECT * FROM Flights WHERE 1 = 1");
```

then you don't need emptyQuery flag and checks and many if else constractions.

```
List<Flight> foundFlights = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder sqlQueryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    sqlQueryBuilder.append("SELECT * FROM Flights WHERE 1 = 1");

    if(flight.getDeparture() != null) {
        sqlQueryBuilder.append("AND Departure = '" + flight.getDeparture() + "'");
    }
```

Comment: I dont think the worry here is checking for the emptyQuery, here the worry is to check if the column fields submitted to the query are empty or null.

Comment: hi @JohnsonAbraham, it was speed review of code and the way to decrease its amount without SQL hint, also do the work on java-side. plus make provided code more "Elegantly". By the way, i think your solution better than mine.